# Need Help To Solve Images Disppeared After Again Form Submiitted?

Tags: php, image, file-upload, image-uploading, image-upload

i have multiple image upload options in the form and they are working fine and update file name in the mysql database columns?

when i uploads image1 then image move on to the server and also it is showing next to `html table columns` now problem is that when i upload `image with file option2` after form submit then `image1 which is on the next to the image1 file option` will be disappeared and in the `mysql database image1 columns will be blank`?

**Multiple Images Uploading Functions**

```
 $id=$_REQUEST['id'];

 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {

 if (!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])) 
 {

 $rnd_1 = rand(11111,99999); 
 $file_name= $rnd_1.'_'.$_FILES['image']["name"];
 $file_path = "uploads/"; 
 $image = new imgMark(); 
 $image->font_path = "arial.ttf"; 
 $image->font_size = 25; 
 $image->water_mark_text = "© www.edge.pk";  
 $image->color = 'CC003E'; 
 $image->opacity = 50; 
 $image->rotation = 0;
 if($image->convertImage('image', $file_name, $file_path))
 $demo_image = $image->img_path;
 }

 if (!empty($_FILES['image1']['name'])) 
 { 
 $rnd_1 = rand(11111,99999); 
 $file_name= $rnd_1.'_'.$_FILES['image1']["name"];
 $file_path = "uploads/"; 
 $image = new imgMark(); 
 $image->font_path = "arial.ttf"; 
 $image->font_size = 35; 
 $image->water_mark_text = "© www.edge.pk";  
 $image->color = 'CC003E'; 
 $image->opacity = 50; 
 $image->rotation = 0;
 if($image->convertImage('image1', $file_name, $file_path))
 $demo_image2 = $image->img_path;
 }

 if (!empty($_FILES['image2']['name'])) 
 { 
 $rnd_1 = rand(11111,99999); 
 $file_name= $rnd_1.'_'.$_FILES['image2']["name"];
 $file_path = "uploads/"; 
 $image = new imgMark(); 
 $image->font_path = "arial.ttf"; 
 $image->font_size = 35; 
 $image->water_mark_text = "© www.edge.pk";  
 $image->color = 'CC003E'; 
 $image->opacity = 50; 
 $image->rotation = 0;
 if($image->convertImage('image2', $file_name, $file_path))
 $demo_image3 = $image->img_path; 
 }
```

**Update Query**

```
UPDATE products SET 
image='$demo_image',addimage1='$demo_image2',addimage2='$demo_image3'
WHERE id='$id'
}
```

**Select Images Query**

```
$query1=mysql_query("select images,addimages1,addimages2 from products 
where id='$id' ")or die("query");
$row2=mysql_fetch_array($query1);

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

Image Upload Option1
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" />
<img src="<?php echo $image['image'] ?>" width="150" height="150" />

Image Upload Option2
<input  type="file" name="image1" id="image1"/>
<img src="<?php echo $image['addimage1'] ?>" width="150" height="150" />

Image Upload Option3
<input  type="file" name="image2" id="image2"/>
<img src="<?php echo $image['addimage2'] ?>" width="150" height="150" />

<input type="submit" class="bg" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lays here:

```
UPDATE products SET 
image='$demo_image',addimage1='$demo_image2',addimage2='$demo_image3'
WHERE id='$id'
}
```

From what I understood you first submit the form where you upload the first image and then you submit the form again where you upload the second image. The reason of this is that during your second upload the variable $demo_image will be blank because you are not sending any value of the input "image" during the resubmit. See here:

```
$demo_image = $image->img_path;
```

$image->img_path is blank, therefore $demo_image will be blank (or NULL? - not sure) as well.

There are many solutions of this problem. You can retrieve data from you db to the form and then resubmit, or test if your variables are blank (or NULL?) and then having different UPDATE commands for different variations, or retrieving data from MySQL just before you run UPDATE and many more.

I'd pick retrieving "old" data from MySQL and then just test if their NULL. If they are not NULL in MySQL, you will just resubmit the same data to your db. Like this:

```
if ($demo_image_from_db!=NULL) $demo_image = $demo_image_from_db;
```

It is possible that there is also a MySQL native function for updating only when NULL - I've heard of COALESCE but I don't exactly know how to use it - that would be definitely the simplest way to do it.

Comment: is that possible i can use `<input type="hidden" name="demo_image" value="<?php echo $image['image'] ?>" />` is it retrive same image from server?

Comment: You could use input hidden where you will just retrieve the data from your MySQL.. `<input type="hidden" name="demo_image_value" value="<?php echo $demo_image_from_db; ?>" />` .. and then again test if it has a value before you are running the UPLOAD command the way I explained. It will then look like this `if ($demo_image_value!="") $demo_image = $demo_image_value;`

Comment: kiellins still same problem after using `input type="hidden"`

Comment: I don't exactly know the way how you did it.. but.. Is the code you posted the actual code you are using? Because I've just noticed a typo in your code - in update query you are using addimage1 and in select query addimages1

Comment: @edgematrix If I helped you mark the answer please, if not you can post your solution so other could learn from it.

Comment: i marked ur answer and second i'm working on it if i will completed then i will paste my script so any one will get help from that script